# ffmpeg: Unable to find a suitable output format for '–i'

Tags: ffmpeg

I am not sure why, but I cannot seem to get a watermark rendered on the bottom right corner of my video using ffmpeg.

I am using the following command:

```
$ ffmpeg –i faded.mov -vf "movie=logo2.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w-10)/2:(main_h-overlay_h-10)/2 [out]" outputvideo3.mov
...
[NULL @ 0x7fa2ec001000] Unable to find a suitable output format for '–i'
–i: Invalid argument
```

Comment: thanks for LordNeckBeard for editing the question to make it look a lot better! Sorry, I am new to stack overflow!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `-` (hyphen), not `–` (en dash).

- Correct: `-i`
- Incorrect: `–i`

Comment: You just made my day!

Comment: gods have names and one written in stone is LordNeckbeard

Comment: Thanks! Had the exact same problem, might have copied a line from some example on a website which has converted the dashes